# Imagemagick replicate css mask-image and background-blend-mode rules

Tags: css, mask, imagemagick-convert, background-blend-mode

I want to translate these CSS rules into Imagemagick's `convert` command(s):

```
.foo {
  background: red url('image.png');
  mask-image: url('mask.png');
  background-blend-mode:multiply;
}
```

Any suggestions?

JSFiddle with using my own sample image here: https://jsfiddle.net/1b4wek70/

Note that both image and mask are the same source but that shouldn't be and issue. I also use `-webkit-mask-image` for Chrome as it still needs to be prefixed so make sure it's viewed on an appropriate browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ImageMagick, I believe that would be (Unix syntax)

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:white \( image.png -fill blue -colorize 100 \) -compose over -composite image.png -compose multiply -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: I think -colorize flag needs percentage to work but even with that I'm still not getting the result I want. I will try getting a quick jsfiddle up.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1b4wek70/ for one of my sample images. I think culprit might be how browser/webkit and imagemagick handles blending/masking with alpha transparency?

Comment: Post the image used so that I can try to duplicated your result. Nevermind. I got it from the link in your file.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to do what you show in your link in your comment.